# Could not play pyvideo in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I'm using Chrome 43 on Windows 7. While I can play youtube, and a lot of online video, except pyvideo.org.

I suppose pyvideo.org is a safe site. How can I play the video from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scroll down on the video's page and on the right side of the page you will find links to play the same video on YouTube and also to download it.